# Holoview, change style option for a Graph

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews

I use holoview for plotting graph ('bokeh' extension)
I want to change default style options (edge color, node color, ...) of my graph.
For plot/graph (width, directedn policy, ...) option I use :

> graph.opts(**my_dict_options)

But this doesn't work for style parameters.
How can I fix that ?

**Edit :**

I use 1.11.2 version, here an example to illustrate my problem :

```
G = nx.karate_club_graph()
dict_options =  dict()
dict_options['node_size'] = 10
dict_options['edge_color'] = 'blue'
dict_options['node_color'] = 'red'
graph = hv.Graph.from_networkx(G,nx.layout.spring_layout).opts(**dict_options)
```

node_size is working, edge_color / node_color are ignored

Comment: Which version are you using? This should work just fine for style options.

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Looks like it's specifically node and edge color that are ignored. I'll file an issue and investigate.